# Showing the Restore Button without a Maximize button

Tags: c#, winforms, restore, maximize

I want to prevent the user from maximizing the Windows Form to full screen so I have disabled the Maximize button. However, I want to be able to have the user 'restore' the Form. When they click the Restore button I want it to show a different, smaller, minified, form, which will show them a maximize button which will return the use to the original form.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

edit:
You don't understand, I'm not preventing the user from resizing the form. Whats happening is when the click the restore button, it will hide the form and open a new one with less controls on it. When they click maximize on the smaller form, it will return to the original form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at a similar problem to this at work and the only solutions I could find involved setting undocumented window styles, which I was not inclined to do.

Therefore the best solution to your problem I would think would be to hide the current minimize/maximize/restore buttons and add your own using some ownerdraw or other commands.

Looking at this from a user interaction perspective I would want the minimize/maximize/restore buttons to do exactly the same thing for your application as they do for all others. Overriding that functionality would create confusion for your users, hence why I would recommend creating different buttons either on the title bar or somewhere else on your interface that perform this function.

Comment: I think I may have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the MaximumSize and MinimumSize and enable the maximize button to get this kind of effect.

Comment: Actually, it moves it to the top right corner when I do that, although it does keep the right size

Comment: In this age of responsive design, I'd consider what John B said -- don't make the 'minified' version a fixed size, and at least allow it to be resized somewhat. If it moves to the top-right corner, you can use the `FormStartPosition.CenterScreen` setting.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the right answer is to make your form resize properly, adapting to any window size and not to constrain the user to what looks right on *your* display at *your* resolution and *your* font size.  Non-resizeable windows are one of the most annoying things I encounter in an application (Windows itself is full of them).

Comment: You don't understand, I'm not preventing the user from resizing the form. Whats happening is when the click the restore button, it will hide the form and open a new one with less controls on it. When they click maximize on the smaller form, it will return to the original form.

Comment: But doesn't that violate the principle of least surprise for the user?    I expect restore to restore the window to the previous floating size I had, and maximize to fill my display.

Comment: This is not a control that would ever be required to go fullscreen.

Comment: On your display, perhaps.  What about the phone or PDA user with a 320x240 or 800x600 display?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation recently, and from a UI design perspective, found a good example in Windows Media Player. It leaves the Minimise, Maximise and Restore buttons as they are, and has a separate button on the bottom right for "Switch to Compact Mode". And in the mini/compact mode, the same button toggles to "Switch to Full Mode". Another alternative example is Skype, which has an additional system icon button just left of the standard minimise button, that toggles between Compact and Standard modes.

(If I had the privilege, I would've preferred to put this as a comment to add to Daemin's accepted answer, still relatively new to StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

'Restoring' a form fires the `Resize` event where you can check if the parent form is no longer `FormWindowState.Maximized`. If not, you can open the child form and hide the parent.

To reverse this, you can 'maximize' the child form by hiding (or disposing) it, then un-hide and set the parent form to `FormWindowState.Maximized`.

The only problem that I can see with this method is that the `Resize` event will likely fire several times before the form reaches a Maximumized state. A flag may be needed to ignore these until the form goes from the current state to the desired state, which can cause an infinite loop.